# Rails parameters contain backslashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working with `button_tag` to create a remote styled answer submission quiz. When pressing this button, instead of posting the new record, it is throwing an error.

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Answer without an ID):`

When looking at the server logs I see it is trying to work with these params when trying to post `Parameters: {"{\"answer_id\":59}"=>nil, "id"=>"15"}`

What I am looking, or expecting to see is this. 
`Parameters: {"answer_id"=>"59", "id"=>"15"}`

Here is the `button_tag` I am using.

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= button_tag "#{answer.answer.titleize}", class: 'btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary', data: {
    remote: true,
    method: :post,
    url:    answer_question_path(@question),
    params: { answer_id: answer.id }
  } %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my response controller which is responsible for submitting the POST request.

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController
    def answer
        question = Question.find(params[:id])
        answer   = question.answers.find(params[:answer_id])
        response = question.responses.find_or_initialize_by(user: current_user)

        if response.update(answer: answer)
            head :ok
        else
            puts 'Something went wrong chief' 
        end
    end

    private

    def responses_params
        params.require(:response).permit(:user_id, :question_id, :answer_id)
    end
end
```

I have tried using `to_json` on the parameter with no success and have not been able to find any solution elsewhere on SO or other forums. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) instead of `button_tag`? That first method has more control over remote without needing to hack around with `data`.

Comment: That's embarrassing. I tried earlier with no success but that seems to have worked now. Thank you.

Comment: No shame in succeeding! If you've got a working solution using that approach showing the adapted code as a self-answer would be educational to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `button_tag` in the feature I am using it for.

`button_tag` creates a button element that defines a submit button, resetbutton or a generic button which can be used in JavaScript. `button_tag` is also an action view helper but is defined as a FormTagHelper.

`button_to` generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options. `button_to` is a UrlHelper while `button_tag` is a ViewHelper.

Below is the `button_tag` code I was using which was creating the issue described above. Using `button_tag` fixed my parameters issue and also looks a bit cleaner. I hope this helps anybody else having issues with `button_tag` in the future.

```
<%= button_tag "#{answer.answer.titleize}", class: 'btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary', data: {
    remote: true,
    method: :post,
    url:    answer_question_path(@question),
    params: { answer_id: answer.id }
  } %>


<%= button_to "#{answer.answer.titleize}", 
      answer_question_path(@question), 
      class: 'btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary',
      params: { answer_id: answer.id },
      remote: true %>
```